# need a help in left join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

table1:

```
name | map_id | reg_id 
abc  |  1     | 5
pqr  |  2     | 5
xyz  |  3     | 5
```

table2:

```
map_id | map_name | is_deleted
 1     | map1     |   0
 2     | map2     |   0
```

my sql query :

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2
              ON t1.map_id = t2.map_id
WHERE  t1.reg_id = 5
       AND t2.is_deleted = 0
```

what the above query does is stops me from retrieving record with `map_id = 3` in table1.

how can i achieve this as well as 'is_deleted check' if the record exists in table2.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `is_deleted` check to the JOIN:

```
select t1.name, t1.map_id, t1.reg_id,  -- replace select * with columns
  t2.map_name, t2.is_deleted
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 
  on t1.map_id = t2.map_id
  and t2.is_deleted = 0
WHERE t1.reg_id = 5;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08730/4).  Your current query is causing the `LEFT JOIN` to act like an `INNER JOIN` because you have the `is_deleted` as a part of the WHERE clause.  If you move that to the JOIN, then you will return the rows from `table2` that have `is_deleted=0` and you will still return all rows from `table1` where `reg_id=5`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it seems this will work. i will implement this in my application and check.

Comment: Yes, because the `and t2.is_deleted = 0` clause was killing the map_id = 3 record. The left join included that record, but `t2.is_deleted` was null. Moving that condition to the join condition is the correct way to do this.